# which non-linear solver is defined for normal distribution?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

would you please help me? in following code Ipopt solver is used to solve the non-linear model. but it seems this solver not is not suitable for normal distribution. would you please help me which one of non-linear solver can be useful for solving the model. Thanks very much.

```
using JuMP,Gurobi, Ipopt
#parameters--------------------------------------------------------
sig=0.86;
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALT= Model(optimizer_with_attributes(Juniper.Optimizer, "nl_solver"=>optimizer_with_attributes(Ipopt.Optimizer, "print_level" => 0),

       "mip_solver"=>optimizer_with_attributes(Gurobi.Optimizer, "logLevel" => 0),"registered_functions" =>[Juniper.register( :f, 1, f; autodiff = true)])

       )

# variables-----------------------------------------------------------------
f(x) = cdf(Normal(0, 1), x);
JuMP.register(ALT, :f, 1, f; autodiff = true);
@variable(ALT, h >= 0);
@variable(ALT, L >= 0);
@variable(ALT, n, Int);
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
@NLexpression(ALT,k7,1-f(L-sig*sqrt(n))+f(-L-sig*sqrt(n)));
#constraints--------------------------------------------------------
@NLconstraint(ALT, f(-L) <= 1/400);
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
@NLobjective(ALT, Min, 1/k7)

optimize!(ALT)
```

this error is there

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: Normal not defined
```

Comment: have you imported Distributions.jl?

Comment: oh my God , I forgot :)))))). thanks very much

Comment: I am sorry. I know my questions are primary. but would you please guide me . after solving the model this message ```Start values are not feasible.
Status of relaxation: INVALID_MODEL``` means that the model is infeasible? Thanks a lot.

Comment: it means that the solver was not able to find a feasible starting solution. I do not have Gurobi, so I cannot test it, but you can try setting some feasible starting values. Still the optimization problem looks strange, as `n` has `Int` restriction and I am not sure which optimizer can handle this (maybe you should try relaxation and then iterate over `n` in outside loop).

Comment: Please consider posting on the more active Julia forum: https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt/13

Comment: I am really grateful for your valuable helping Prof. Bogumił Kamiński. when I limited the  variables the solver could find feasible solutions.